# What configuration is required to get micrometer with spring-boot to output jvm_info{} guage?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer

I have a number of non spring-boot services which generate JVM metrics automatically using `io.prometheus` `simpleclient_hotspot`.

I am trying to obtain parity with these and the JVM metrics produced from my spring-boot services which are using micrometer's default settings.

Is there some additional configuration for micrometer which I need in order for it to generate metrics such as:

```
# TYPE jvm_info gauge
jvm_info{version="
...
jvm_memory_bytes_used
jvm_memory_pool_bytes_max
etc...
```

?

I appreciate micrometer out of the box is logging: `jvm_memory_used_bytes` which doesn't match the name of the same metric from simpleclient_hotspot :(

I would like to achieve consistency if possible, and `jvm_info` would be particularly useful from micrometer/spring-boot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look into `NamingConvention` found in the micrometer core library.  There are several examples of using it to convert names to different monitoring systems (look for classes implenting `NamingConvention`).  For example, if you're using Prometheus (which it looks like you might be), you could look at `PrometheusNamingConvention` as an example.  It looks like you'll be interested in implementing/overriding the `public String name(String name, Meter.Type type, @Nullable String baseUnit)` method.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question(s)

1. I ended up implementing this for JVM Version Info:

```java
    import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge;
    import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    /**
     * Migrated From simpleclient_hotspot/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/hotspot/VersionInfoExports.java
     * Because its not included in Micrometer.
     */
    @Component
    public class JvmVersionInfoExports {
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JvmVersionInfoExports.class);
    
        public JvmVersionInfoExports(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
            LOGGER.info("Adding JVM Metrics");
            Gauge.builder("jvm_info", () -> 1L)
                    .description("JVM version info")
                    .tag("version", System.getProperty("java.runtime.version", "unknown"))
                    .tag("vendor", System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor", "unknown"))
                    .tag("runtime", System.getProperty("java.runtime.name", "unknown"))
                    .register(meterRegistry);
        }
    }
```

2. I ended up implementing this for OS Version Info:

```java
    import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge;
    import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Component
    public class OsVersionInfoExports {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OsVersionInfoExports.class);
    
        public OsVersionInfoExports(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
            LOGGER.info("Adding OS Metrics");
            Gauge.builder("os_info", () -> 1L)
                    .description("OS version info")
                    .tag("version", System.getProperty("os.version", "unknown"))
                    .tag("arch", System.getProperty("os.arch", "unknown"))
                    .tag("name", System.getProperty("os.name", "unknown"))
                    .register(meterRegistry);
        }
    }
```

Although theses misuse the Micrometer Gauge they provide me with the compatibility I need to track these details across services using a mix of Micrometer and Prometheus HotSpot libraries.

Comment: AFAICT it's done automatically [since micrometer v.1.7.0](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/commit/17b6a56bf82428b3b374a27b68b03d60f0fd4e95).